# Can't Install "pygame" Even I Installed It With "pip"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, modulenotfounderror

[image: My VS Code]

As you can see, I installed "pygame" with "pip" but I still got an `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'`.  I tried to uninstall it and install it again and again many times but I still got this error. The weird thing is that there is also a "WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip". What can I do for this?

Comment: Did you try running the code?

Comment: according to your terminal pygame is successfully installed try to close vscode and reopen it

Comment: reopen vs code, i am pretty sure if you install a module while vs code is running, it wont know it is installed

Comment: Yes I tried all of your comments. Is there anything more I need to do?

Comment: Maybe multiple python installs or a venv? In VSCode in the bottom bar, right side: click "3.10.4 64-bit" and make sure the correct python.exe is selected.